# Getting a WMS ImageLayer and layering it over an OpenStreetMap Layer - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wms, mapsui

I am trying to get the map from a WMS to layer on a MapsUI map. However the WMS layer does not appear on the map. I have a simple view with just a MapControl (mapControl)

```
//create wms layer
public async Task CreateLayerAsync()
{
    var layer =  new ImageLayer("NOAA WMS")
    {
        DataSource = await CreateWmsProviderAsync(),
        Style = new RasterStyle()
    };
    mapControl.Map?.Layers.Add(layer);
}

private static async Task<WmsProvider> CreateWmsProviderAsync()
{
    const string wmsUrl = "https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/eventdriven/services/radar/radar_base_reflectivity_time/ImageServer/WMSServer";

    var provider = await WmsProvider.CreateAsync(wmsUrl);
    provider.ContinueOnError = true;
    provider.TimeOut = 20000;
    provider.CRS = "EPSG:84";
    provider.AddLayer("0");
    provider.SetImageFormat(provider.OutputFormats[1]);
    return provider;
}
```

The link to the WMS GetCapabilities document is [here](https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/eventdriven/services/radar/radar_base_reflectivity_time/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS).

Any ideas? This is my first time diving into GIS and  map rendering, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you show this map on top of the often use osm tile layer you need to set the CRS like this:
`provider.CRS = "EPSG:3857";`

If you want to show the NOAA layer without other layers you could use
`provider.CRS = "EPSG:4326";`. and not EPSG:84

Comment: thank you! setting the CRS to EPSG:3857 was the solution for layering it over a OSM layer.